# How do I stop a http redirect from corrupting my maven repository?

Tags: maven-2, m2eclipse, http-redirect

I use the m2eclipse plugin, and I commute on a ferry with wifi service provided by Boigo.  When I try to access anything via http on the ferry, if I haven't already logged in any request gets redirected to a login screen.  The problem is that if for any reason eclipse decides to refresh its maven dependencies before I've logged in, I get 'jars' and 'poms' full of the Boingo redirect response which then prevents my build from succeeding.  Is there any solution to this problem aside from making sure never to launch Eclipse until after I've logged into the wifi service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Preferences->Maven and uncheck **Download repository index updates on startup**. At a pinch you can select **Offline** check.